# Custom wordpress category loop listing page

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories

I'm trying to build a wordpress theme for a magazine site I plan on launching and I'm kind of stuck on a certain issue.

I'm listing my posts in a 3 column layout and I'd like to create a page where I can list all my categories along with a category image in the same style. I was thinking that wordpress had a loop function for listing categories but I must have been mistaken.  Is this something that's possible?

I plan on having quite a few categories, and I have a custom post type with it's own taxonomy and I'd like to create a page that lists all the categories along with category descriptions.

I am very much a novice at coding.  Here's the html prototype for the design I'm building in wordpress: [link](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/455757/headsaflame.com/Headsaflame.com%20Build6/home.html)

You can see how I have the posts laid out. What I'm looking to build is a custom page template that will list all my categories in the same format.

Any advice or direction anyone could give me would be awesome! I don't know any other web developers where I'm from.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does have a built in function for getting your categories. You can use PHP to do this. If you want to do it dynamically, you could use either a foreach or a while loop. Since categories on wordpress are stored by numeric ID's (ex: home.php = 1). For the pictures part I would simply set the pictures name to the same ID as the category, and include something like /img + i + .jpg, where i is the current category your loop is on. You can find more info on how to set this all up here [on the wordpress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates), also you might find some of the info [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-by-category-homephp-template) useful.